# Caesar cipher in C, upper and lower case

Tags: c, algorithm, cryptography, ascii, caesar-cipher

I have to produce Caesar cipher decoder -- for both lower and upper case, but I am not able to think of an easy solution to do this (or at the moment even working one).

At the moment I have this loop to decipher the code by given shift `i`:

```
char* s1 = "qrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnop";
int s1s = strlen(s1);
int i = 16;
char tmp[s1s+1];
for (int j = 0; j < s1s; ++j) {
    char tmp_s = (char) ((int) s1[j]-i);
    if(tmp_s<65){
        tmp_s+=58;
    }
    tmp[j]=tmp_s;
}
tmp[s1s]='\0';
```

Output should be `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, at the moment it is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`.

I have tried some conditions, but can't really figure out the right one.

Comment: `'l'-16 = 92` so [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) char `\\`, or  `'k'-16 = 91` so [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) char `[`....What's the problem?....

Comment: Yes and those six characters in ASCII are cousing me trouble, I need the output to be different than my current output is - so shift k-16 in my cipher should be actually k-22 in ASCII table.

Comment: `int s1s = strlen(s1); char tmp[s1s];` --- this is liable to result in undefined behaviour, because you forgot to add an additional byte to store the `'\0'` string terminator. Also, why are you ignoring the last character of `s1`? (i.e., shouldn't your loop statement be more like `for (int j = 0; j < s1s; ++j)`?)

Comment: Fixed, in complete code it is correctly this way, just this excerpt was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests are not complete. Consider the "ASCII space":

```
\0 ... 'A' ... 'Z' ... 'a' ... 'z' ...
```

You have here 5 areas:

1. characters before 'A'.
2. characters between 'A' and 'Z'.
3. characters between 'Z' and 'a'.
4. characters between 'a' and 'z'.
5. characters after 'z'.

What you need is to handle characters in areas 1 and 3 once shifted (since you're only performing subtractions, area 5 will never be reached).

You should also use characters in your conditions instead of numerical values for readability. Try:

```
char* s1 = "qrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnop";
int s1s = strlen(s1);
int i = 16;
char tmp[s1s+1];
for (int j = 0; j < s1s; ++j) {
    char tmp_s = (char) ((int) s1[j]-i);
    if(tmp_s < 'A'){ /* "area 1" */
        tmp_s += 'z'-'A' + 1; /* shift between 'a' and 'z' */
    }
    else if(tmp_s < 'a' && s1[j] >= 'a'){ /* "area 3" */
        tmp_s += 'Z'-'a' + 1; /* shift between 'A' and 'Z' */
    }
    tmp[j]=tmp_s;
}
tmp[s1s]='\0';
```

The code may need further adaptations if you allow `i` to be high enough to "jump" more than one area.

Comment: In area 1, I believe there should be also +1, because its otherwise shifted. But the issue is still there for my shift 16, for ex. when I have 'a', I should jump to large 'K', but instead of I jump to large Q, because the shift should be actually plus the Z-a shift. I cant really think of an condition to fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to all the values. I edited my answer with a working version